# Extract embedded number from string - JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This deals with the general problem of extracting a signed number from a string that also contains hyphens.

Can someone please come up with the regex for the following:

```
 "item205"             => 205  
 "item-25              => -25  
 "item-name-25"        => -25
```

Basically, we want to extract the number to the end of the string, including the sign, while ignoring hyphens elsewhere.

The following works for the first two but returns "-name-25" for the last:

```
var sampleString = "item-name-25";
sampleString.replace(/^(\d*)[^\-^0-9]*/, "")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason this was voted down? Seems perfectly valid...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.match` instead:

```
"item-12-34".match(/-?\d+$/);  // ["-34"]
```

The regexp says "possible hyphen, then one or more digits, then the end of the string".

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `replace`. Instead, use `match` and write the regex for what you actually want (because that's a lot easier):

```
var regex = /-?\d+$/;
var match = "item-name-25".match(regex);
> ["-25"]
var number = match[0];
```

One thing about your regex though: in a character class you can only meaningfully use `^` once (right at the beginning) to mark it as a negated character class. It doesn't work for every single element individually. That means that your character class actually corresponds to "any character that is not a `-`, `^` or a digit.

Comment: Was just about to post this. Hah.