# Get Input field array index in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of input field like this;

```
<input type="text" name="pname[283]" value="" class="input" />
<input type="text" name="pname[678]" value="" class="input" />
<input type="text" name="pname[876]" value="" class="input" />
<input type="text" name="pname[454]" value="" class="input" />
```

Now i want to get the array indexes of every field inside foreach loop something like this

```
$('.input').each(function(e) {
   console.log('get array indexes');  eg: 283, 678, 876, 454  
 });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract embedded number from string - JavaScript Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768129/extract-embedded-number-from-string-javascript-regex)

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? Any attempts at all? `.index()` + `.slice()`, or a regular expression, or `.split()`, or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the name attribute manually.

```js
$('.input').each(function() {
   const name = $(this).prop('name');
   console.log(name.slice(name.indexOf('[') + 1, -1)); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="pname[283]" value="" class="input" />
<input type="text" name="pname[678]" value="" class="input" />
<input type="text" name="pname[876]" value="" class="input" />
<input type="text" name="pname[454]" value="" class="input" />
```